# Does any namespace changes EF to 4.1 from 4.0, could not find AttributeConfigurationConvention<T1, T2, T3>

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-ctp5

I implemented AttributeConfigurationConvention  for decimal precision attribute for EF 4.0. It was worked well for our apps but install 4.1 I got compile time Error    ;

> 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.DecimalPropertyConfiguration'
>   is inaccessible due to its protection
>   level

Does any namespace change or EF 4.1 doesn't need this implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: question could be close... I found Rowan Miller (MSFT) comments on microsoft social forums, he said that; 
"EF 4.1 does not include support for custom conventions. CTP5 included an early preview of conventions but the feature was not ready to be included in the supported go-live releases.
 
~Rowan"

Comment: You can add your comment as your own answer and accept it then because... it's just the right answer. It's better than leaving this question open forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question could be close... I found Rowan Miller (MSFT) comments on microsoft social forums, he said that; "EF 4.1 does not include support for custom conventions. CTP5 included an early preview of conventions but the feature was not ready to be included in the supported go-live releases. ~Rowan"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that EF 4.0 had this class at all. Perhaps you mean EF CTP5? Anyway, for EF 4.1 `DecimalPropertyConfiguration` is in namespace

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration
```

It's possible that the namespace changed indeed from CTP5 to EF 4.1.

Comment: hi, DecimalPropertyConfiguration stay in this namespace, but AttributeConfigurationConvention... because we need to apply DecimalPropertyConfiguration with simple attribute to our decimal model members..